# sent an email text-area content white-space style not working

Tags: whitespace, nodemailer

I have an email with a text-area input field and one value contains a string with multiple lines. (enter-key) When viewed in my local email template, the white-space (pre-wrap) is not working.

Any one have idea to how to fix it?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: No worry, I resolved it  @lazzy-ms